# By default assignee=reporter in jira

Tags: jira

Whenever i edit the subtask issues the screen sets the assignee's value from reporter field.

for ex: if reporter is xxx and assignee is yyy . When i edit this sub-task issue the screen shows that assignee=xxx.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this happens to you, i tried to reproduce it but works fine for me.

Do you have any plugins? any custom field scipts? any post function script?

Anyway, you can solve that by one of the following ways:

1. Post function script as explained [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/66562/set-assignee-to-some-specific-user-in-post-function-script)
2. Plugin like [Behaviours Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours) or [Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss)
3. Add a custom filed, edit it's description and add a jQuery script that will set the `assignee` option

If you need any help or have question on any of the solutions feel free to ask.

Comment: You are right. I think this is the problem because of JQuery. but i verified the JQuery script for assignee field.It seems to be okay. But still it behaves like this.

Comment: Removing the script, will it affect anything?  and can you explain me how the pop-up window generated in jira 5?

Comment: not really sure what do you mean.. Jira's client side generated the page based on the screens and fields you've defined, and fills them with content by making ajax call to the server. To better understand what the script does and what will happen if you remove it you'll have to post it here or at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or such.